# Celery won't traverse Django foreign key relationships

Tags: django, celery, django-queryset, django-celery

I'm running two instances on Heroku:
  1. Gunicorn
  2. Celeryd

In my email templates I have something to the effect of:

```
orders.orderitem_set.all
```

When I render these emails via the web instance (ie. without Celery) I get a list of order items (as expected).

However, when I render these templates with Celery, the list is empty.

Why won't Celery traverse foreign key relationships in templates and how do I know what is in and out of scope?

Comment: Celery is an asynchronous process framework. How does that fit in with rendering the email? Could you include some code?

Comment: @KevinLondon updated above. I'm running two instances: a web and celery instance. I have many unique templates to render so I want to do them in parallel on my Celery instance. Could it be that the db isn't yet updated with the fk relationship changes from the web instance?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs for your Heroku instance in Celery? are you passing the same information to the template, fetched from the db or otherwise? I think I'd want to see the celery task.

Comment: You use this in an email?

Comment: Look at "Advice No.7: Don't pass Database/ORM objects to tasks" in https://denibertovic.com/posts/celery-best-practices/

Comment: @Ingaz thank you. If you'd like to submit that link and quote as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the django database objects are stale at the moment of execution of the celery tasks.

This problem was noted by Deni Bertovic in https://denibertovic.com/posts/celery-best-practices/

> You shouldn't pass Database objects (for instance your User model) to a background task because the serialized object might contain stale data. What you want to do is feed the task the User id and have the task ask the database for a fresh User object.

Comment: @grokpot: thank you very much. My English is terrible.